# How to populate Table View in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, macos, tableview, xamarin, cells

I'm trying to port a C# Windows application to Mac but I'm stuck trying to populate a table view with a bunch of strings. The table view seems to come with two columns which is good for me but I don't know how to access the cells, rows, columns or add items. In Windows, I did something like:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    somelistbox.Items.Add(item)
}
```

What could I do in Xamarin? Do I need another view to add to table view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a NSTableViewDataSource for your table.  Typically you will create your own custom class that inherits from NSTableViewDataSource, then override these methods

You will assign an instance of your custom Source class to the DataSource property of the TableView.  Your DataSource will probably have some internal data structure (ie, a List, or something more complex) that you populate based on whatever your data is.  Then you will customize the DataSource methods to respond appropriately based on the length of your data, etc.

Let's assume that your data is a simple string[]:

```
// populate this in constructor, via service, setter, etc - whatever makes sense
private string[] data;

// how many rows are in the table
public int NumberOfRowsInTableView(NSTableView table)
{
  return data.length;
}

// what to draw in the table
public NSObject ObjectValueForTableColumn (NSTableView table, NSTableColumn col, int row)
{
  // assume you've setup your tableview in IB with two columns, "Index" and "Value"

  string text = string.Empty;

  if (col.HeaderCell.Title == "Index") {
text = row.ToString();
  } else {
    text = data [row];
  }

  return new NSString (text);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that first method returns 'table.RowCount'. Could you show me how to set up the second method?

Comment: or would it be something like this except in C#? [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html)

Comment: I expanded my example to include some more detail

Comment: The app runs but it's not displaying anything in the tableview. I created an object (`TableViewSource source = new TableviewSource()`) of the custom tableviewdatasource class and set tableview data source properties like this: `tableview.Datasource = source`. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you hook up the data source to the TableView?  Are any of the table source methods being called?  The logic in my example is tied to how my Table is setup in IB.  You might need to make some tweaks.

Comment: I did connect the inner Tableview (which is tableview itself...took time to figure that one) to the header file (in Xcode) but did I need to connect the NSTableColumn as well?

Comment: Fixed! You needed to override `int GetRowCount(NSTableView table)` and `NSObject GetObjectValue(NSTableView table, NSTableColumn column, int row)`. Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @cansik Your welcome ^^. It's been a while but I think the method was just a quick fix. Hope it gets the job done though!