# How to access string values from Table View in Xamarin

Tags: c#, string, macos, cell, xamarin

From [How to populate view in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293613/how-to-populate-table-view-in-xamarin), I was able to set up the table view with a bunch of strings but how do I access the string values that were selected by a user? I understand that in the previous question, I had to override some methods to fill the Table View. Would I have to do that to access the string values? If so, which method do I need to override?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my question. It took time to figure it out, but what needs to be done is:

```
1. Go to the .xib file in Xcode.
2. Double or triple click the inner cell to get the cell isolated.
3. Connect that cell to the controller file or the .h file in Xcode. 
4. Save. 

1. Then go to Xamarin.
2  Use use the table view object, which in my case is `tableview`
3. Set the object's `Cell` property to the the `NSTextFieldCell` object. `tableview.Cell = yourNSTextfieldObject`
4. To get the string value: `tableview.Cell.StringValue`
```